# How to create project templates in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I wanna create **Custom project templates** like existing `Singleview` application, `Utility` application & other application templates but with my own files.

For this i googled alot and found some good links also. But none of them seems to be work for me.

I was following [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109372/Creating-an-Xcode-Project-Template#). But at some point i am struck.

please share any useful info or link even your suggestions.

Thanks,
Tarun

Answer (score 0):

You can't create Custom Project template in Xcode. So Use Empty Template For Your Application.
this ll help u lot.

Comment: Thanks Ankit..But i have created it using a template on Github. I have modified almost all roots and relative information.
This url may help others like i got:

http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/

Simply download the template and paste it under templates folder. Remember this is for Xcode 4.2 only. J

Comment: Then u have to try high level Xml. because Every IB and Template create in XML.