# Create a template for existing project ios

Tags: xcode4

I have several alike project and i want to skip the process of creating new file and project for every project.  I read about project template and i wonder if someone has a good tutorial or reference so that i can implement my project templates. Its basically IPhone development please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's not trivial to add new templates to the ones Apple supplies with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531720/how-to-create-project-templates-in-xcode-4-2), but one easy solution is that you can create an empty project with just the bare things you want to be common between all of your projects. Then duplicate your new pseudo-template app and you can customize and fill out the code from there.

If you *do* want to create custom Xcode project templates, [here is a tutorial I found that might help you out](http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/).

Comment: is it possible to add file and framework within the custom template ?